# pyopenssl, twisted with let's encrypt: server's certificate chain is incomplete

Tags: python, ssl, lets-encrypt, pyopenssl, twisted.web

I want to use let's encrypt on my twisted server, but on the latest Chrome for Android, I receive:

`the identity of this website has not been verified`

Similar message on the latest Firefox for Ubuntu.

My SSL Report from ssllabs.com:

This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B.

My relevant code:

```py
from OpenSSL import crypto

from twisted.internet import ssl

privkey=open('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mindolia.com/privkey.pem', 'rt').read()
certif=open('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mindolia.com/fullchain.pem', 'rt').read()

privkeypyssl=crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,privkey)
certifpyssl=crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,certif)

contextFactory=ssl.CertificateOptions(privateKey=privkeypyssl, certificate=certifpyssl)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create the `CertificateOptions` including the chain certificates is to use the [pem](https://pem.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library, like so:

```
from pem.twisted import certificateOptionsFromFiles

contextFactory = certificateOptionsFromFiles(
    '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mindolia.com/privkey.pem',
    '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mindolia.com/fullchain.pem')
```

Also, for direct Let's Encrypt integration with Twisted, you can use [txacme](https://txacme.readthedocs.io/), provided that your Twisted application is running on port 443 (or port 443 is forwarded to it).

Answer (score 0):

[solution here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/pyopenssl-twisted-servers-certificate-chain-is-incomplete/18591/2)

```py
from OpenSSL import crypto

from twisted.internet import ssl

privkey=open('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mindolia.com/privkey.pem', 'rt').read()
certif=open('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mindolia.com/cert.pem', 'rt').read()
chain=open('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mindolia.com/chain.pem', 'rt').read()

privkeypyssl=crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,privkey)
certifpyssl=crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,certif)
chainpyssl=[crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,chain)]
contextFactory=ssl.CertificateOptions(privateKey=privkeypyssl,certificate=certifpyssl,extraCertChain=chainpyssl)
```